# Get specific two pixel from the bitmap for processing

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have an image on which I want to process pixel number 159 and 160 specifically. I am running this code but it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I think the way I have declared that array that is the problem.

```
int[] twoPositions = {159, 160};
bitmap.GetgetPixels(twoPositions, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height); //exception line (ArrayIndex....)
```

how to declare array in a way which will give me 0 row, 159th and 160th column pixel?
thank you in advance...

Comment: Assuming that's supposed to be the `Bitmap#getPixels()` method, you're not using it correctly. Instead, use the `Bitmap#getPixel(int x, int y)` method.

Comment: getPixel is useful when I want one pixel here I want two pixels (0, 159) and (0, 160)..

Comment: Why don't you just call it twice, if you only need two pixels? If you really want to use `getPixels()`, you should refer to the docs to see how it's used: `bitmap.getPixels(twoPositions, 0, width, 159, 0, 2, 1);`. You don't need to initialize any values in the array.

Comment: yes that option i tried and working well just wanted to see if it works this way or not... thank you for the guidance...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Can't blame ya for wanting to learn something new. Cheers!